# Set negative values in a array to zero by using the if conditional

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I have a function of some variables, which will yield an array consisted of both negative and positive values (Real). But since only positive values are physically meaningful to me, I want to set all negative values inside the array to be zero.

I have provided my code related to this function below:

The reason I declare a temporary variable 'res' is that I try to build in an IF-ELSE in the position I marked in code as follows:

```
If (res >= 0) Then
   result = res
Else
   result = 0
End If
```

But the error says a scalar-valued expression for S_A if required here.

If instead of res we use res(il,ir) is used,

```
If (res(il,ir) >= 0) Then
   result(il,ir) = res(il,ir)
Else
   result = 0
End If
```

the error says error `#6351: The number of subscripts is incorrect`.

Is there any way to implement this idea?

```
 Function somefunction(x,y,il,ir) Result(result)

 !! ---- begin of declaration ---------------------------

 Implicit None

 !! boundary indices
 Integer,            Intent ( in ) :: il,ir
 !! the vars
 Real ( kind = rk ), Intent ( in ), Dimension ( il:ir ) :: x,y
 !! the result
 Real ( kind = rk ), Dimension ( il:ir ) :: result
 !! temp vars
 Real ( kind = rk ), Dimension ( il:ir ) :: res
 !! loop index
 Integer :: i

 !! ---- end of declaration -----------------------------

 res     = x+y
 SA = S_A
 !!IF-ELSE!!
 End Function somefunction
```

Comment: Welcome, please take the Welcome [tour]. Please use code formatting for code.

Comment: If you want to use If you'll need to loop over the indices. But by far the simplest way to do this is not by If, but by using Where

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have an `if` statement element wise on an array, you should use the `where` statement, for example:

```
program min0
    implicit none
    real :: res(5, 5), result(5, 5)
    call random_number(res)
    res=res-0.5

    print '(5(F5.2,X))', res

    where (res>=0)
        result = res
    elsewhere
        result = 0
    end where

    print *, '---------------------------------------'
    print '(5(F5.2,X))', result
end program min0
```

I don't know why you get a subscript error, it might help if you tell us which line of the code the error occurs. But of course in the second code, you update a single element of `result` if `res` is larger than 0, but set the whole array `result` to 0 if it isn't. This is almost certainly not what you want.

Cheers

Comment: What about -0?  If OP really needs/wants only non-negative entries in the array, your code won't work.

Comment: @evets From the question it is clear than the OP wants elements which are >=0. Whether you can or cannot call them non-negative... I do not think it is a problem.

Answer (score 0):

The function appears to take in X and Y dimensioned from (il:if)... say from (3:6), so a vector. However the index later says (il,ir) which means it is a 2 dimensional array.

WHERE seems like a good choice. Another would be a logical MASK to associate the where-positions. It makes sense is PACK and unpack are usd,

Why even say what size the vectors are?

```
ELEMENTAL Function somefunction(x,y) Result(Res)

!! ---- begin of declaration ---------------------------

Implicit None

Real ( kind = rk ), Intent (IN), Dimension (:) :: x,y
!! the result
Real ( kind = rk ), Dimension ( il:ir ) :: res
!! loop index
Integer :: i

!! ---- end of declaration -----------------------------

res     = x+y
WHERE res <= 0
  Res = 0
ENDWHERE
!!IF-ELSE!!
End Function somefunction
```

Then on the calling side... call the function over the range of undecided you want.

```
Z(1:5) = somefunction(X(1:5),Y(1:5))
```

Comment: PACK would be used if you want a new shorter array omitting the negative values.  In my view , result = max(res,0.) looks easier than WHERE, but perhaps I'm influenced by years of work with optimization.

Comment: The fact the array is dimensioned as rank=2 and the example call is rank=1 would explain the fact it does not compile. Worrying about the implimentatuon, and its speed... seems a bit academic? Let's fix the subscripts first.